# Where would I source components to build this IC and credit card sized Bluetooth device?

Tags: integrated-circuit, smart-card

I'm interested in building a [modified version of this device](https://onlycoin.com/), however add custom IC work to it.

I'm not an electrical engineer, however I know what features I want in this form factor. Specifically I'd like to build it as they describe, however I'd like to also do some smartcard-like computation on it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how this would be built?

Comment: It's years since I've seen a magnetic card-swipe device used. It's all [EMV smart-card](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EMV) ("chip & pin") where I live. Even that's increasingly being replaced by [contactless payment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contactless_payment). Magnetic swipe is about as secure and modern as a fax machine.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick - merits aside that is a complaint which is "too localized" to invalidate the question - magnetic swipe is still quite dominant in the US.

Answer (score 2):

Squeezing that sort of functionality into a credit card form factor is not easy.  You can't use regular circuit board fabrication techniques because the end product needs to be thin enough to fit into a card reader.  It probably costs hundreds of thousands to millions in NREs to make a device like that as it likely requires one or more custom ICs that need to be wire-bonded inside the card.  And then you need a very thin display.  And a bluetooth module.  And a properly positioned and sufficiently durable and somehow on-the-fly programmable magnetic strip.  And a very thin battery and some sort of charghing interface.  Adding a smartcard interface is trivial compared to the rest of it - you just need to expose a few contact pads in the right location and add the smart card communication and computation functionality, which is mostly software apart of the serial interface which I believe is I2C.

I don't think it would be possible to 'merge' a separate smart card onto the device, though, the same way you can a regular credit or debit card.  The idea behind a smart card is that it is essentially impossible to duplicate.  Somehow, they encryption keys in the smart card would need to be transferred onto the universal card.  Smart cards are designed to not reveal their contents even under significant reverse engineering efforts.  Nobody is going to add a 'back door' to allow for this on their cards.  A possible alternative is to provide the universal card's key to the bank, but that would mean the universal card's key would be accessible, and this would be a major security issue.